Is it possible to install Netskope remotly on MacOS via Crowdstrike?
I need to install Netskope on an Imac but the user is on remote. I have an access to the mac through Crwdstrike.
Is it possible to install Netskope via crowdstrike via the remote access ?
I found only install by email invitation

According to Netskope's website their application can be installed via three methods: Email Invite, PLIST and MDM Deployment. Your best bet would be PLIST but this question does sound a little sketchy, how come you cannot access the mac locally?
